# Socket.on in Angular

Tags: angular, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am making a chat app with sockets and Angular, is it necessary for me to create a hidden component in the root component to listen for socket responses?Anyone help?

Comment: Angular services are probably the correct choice..

Comment: But I want to be able to retrieve socket data from any page in the app. Isn't it necessary to make a hidden component to retrieve data?

Answer (score 1):

No components you would use for UI releated. You should use a service, that does this. If its needed across the whole app. You should initialize the service from the app.component.ts

edit:

Adding a fake service as example:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FakeWebsocketService {
  fakeWebIO: any;

  private _messages$ = new BehaviorSubject<FakeMessageExample>(null);

  // connect in app.component
  connect(connectionString: string) {
    // assming its some kind of call back class you use form websockets
    this.fakeWebIO.connect(connectionString, (message:     FakeMessageExample) => {
      this._messages$.next(message);
    });
  }
  //connect for use in component
  getReceivedMessages(): Observable<FakeMessageExample> {
    return this._messages$.asObservable();
  }
}
export interface FakeMessageExample {
  createdAt: Date;
  message: string;
  type: string;
}
```

in your app component ts you would then connect to the service

and in the components you need messages from the websocket you can subscribe to the messages received. This would across the whole app.

the example code is far from perfect. But its more of an example of how you could do it.

Comment: But I want to be able to retrieve socket data from any page in the app. Isn't it necessary to make a hidden component to retrieve data?

Comment: If you initialize it in the app component, that service would act as a singleton, since its injected in root. So what ever data you have you can put in a shareable observable or in a behavior subject, then any component that needs data from this service can just read from the same service.

Comment: I don't want to initialize the connection in the root component. I need login authentication to create the connection, so what do I need to do to get data on all pages except the login page?